# Ways to categorise data?

Tags: python, finance

I wan't to allocate downloaded data (csv) into for simplicity say 3 categories. Has anyone got any tips or similar projects i could look at or python tools i should look at.

## 3 categories are...

1. Shares: Include the following `a,b,c`
2. Bonds: Include the following `d,e,f`
3. Cash: `g`

My downloaded data may have any combination of the above investments with any value.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GU7jVLA-YzqRTxyLMdbymdJ6b1RtB09bpOjIDX6eJok/edit?usp=sharing

Thats 2 basic example of what the data will be downloaded as and what I want it to be converted to.

The real data will have 10-15 investments and approx 4 catergories I just want to know is possible to sort like this? It gets tricky as we have longer investment names and some are similar but sorted into different catergories.

If some one could point me in the right direction, i.e do i need a dictionary or some basic framework or code to look at that would be awesome.

Keen to learn but don't know where to start cheers - this is my first proper coding project.

Im not to fussed about the formatting of the output, as long as it clearly categorises the info and sums each category i'm happy :)

Comment: Wan't is a very unique contraction

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a framework, just the builtins will do (as usual in Python).

```py
from collections import defaultdict

# Input data "rows".  These would probably be loaded from a file.

raw_data = [
    ('a', 1000.00),
    ('b', 2000.00),
    ('d', 3000.00),
    ('e', 4000.00),
    ('g', 5000.00),
    ('g', 10000.00),
    ('c', 5000.00),
    ('d', 2000.00),
    ('a', 4000.00),
    ('e', 5000.00),
]

# Category definitions, mapping a category name to the row "types" (first column).

categories = {
    'Shares': {'a', 'b', 'c'},
    'Bonds': {'d', 'e', 'f'},
    'Cash': {'g'},
}

# Build an inverse map that makes lookups faster later.
# This will look like e.g. {"a": "Shares", "b": "Shares", ...}

category_map = {}
for category, members in categories.items():
    for member in members:
        category_map[member] = category

# Initialize an empty defaultdict to group the rows with.

rows_per_category = defaultdict(list)

# Iterate through the raw data...

for row in raw_data:
    type = row[0]  # Grab the first column per row,
    category = category_map[type]  # map it through the category map (this will crash if the category is undefined), 
    rows_per_category[category].append(row)  # and put it in the defaultdict.

# Iterate through the now collated rows in sorted-by-category order:

for category, rows in sorted(rows_per_category.items()):
    # Sum the second column (value) for the total.
    total = sum(row[1] for row in rows)

    # Print header.
    print("###", category)

    # Print each row.
    for row in rows:
        print(row)

    # Print the total and an empty line.
    print("=== Total", total)
    print()
```

This will output something like

```
### Bonds
('d', 3000.0)
('e', 4000.0)
('d', 2000.0)
('e', 5000.0)
=== Total 14000.0

### Cash
('g', 5000.0)
('g', 10000.0)
=== Total 15000.0

### Shares
('a', 1000.0)
('b', 2000.0)
('c', 5000.0)
('a', 4000.0)
=== Total 12000.0
```

Comment: unreal - thanks heaps will have a play around tomorrow thanks heaps!!